# Why is the server getting Kotlin compilation errors?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin builds fine locally. However, it does not work properly on the server.

Below is the error log.

```
 /root/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin/kotlinc: line 80: 34 Killed "${JAVACMD:=java}" $JAVA_OPTS "${java_args[@]}" -cp "${kotlin_app[@]}" "${kotlin_args[@]}"
```

Why does this error occur?

The server is running as a docker command in the Ubuntu 18.04 environment.

Below is the dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install sudo -y
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
RUN chmod u+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh && sdk install kotlin"
ENV PATH /root/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin:$PATH
```

Additionally, I am using version 13 of jdk.

Comment: you may answer to your question yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was docker container memory problem. I increased the docker container from 256mb to 1gb and it works fine. Thank you for trying to help.